# Stop server thread after browser stop loading

Tags: java, http, jakarta-ee, servlets, tcp

I am trying to process some business logic after user hit a URL. There will be a heavy loop running in server side. The browser will be loading (we can see the spinning animation on top) while waiting server return the result.

We don't discuss is that correct or not to perform heavy loop in HTTP connection, my question is that, while the browser is waiting for the result, and, if user want to stop the processing, by closing the browser/tab or pressing ESCAPE or pressing the "X" cross button (at the browser bar), likely, the browser will stop to receive any data from server side. Now, my problem is, the server thread that is processing heavy loop will not stop somehow (even browser not to receive data anymore). How am I going to stop that?

I thought that, according TCP transmission, if one end of sockets is closed, another end will be notified and closed as well. I expect my server will have something like "socket close exception" thing thrown out by the `Servlet`. But it is not, so the loop in `Servlet` is still running until it finished. Any idea how can I stop it? It will lead to "Out of memory" issue if the user keep on hitting the URL and cancel the request.

Comment: Nah, you can not stop the thread.

Comment: TCP won't notice a closed socket until you try to write to the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do something like this:

1. Create service for processing your heavy loop in new threads (manually created by you).
2. When user hits URL in browser create thread with heavy loop in new thread (by processing service) and return to user some internal id of this thread (this id may be generated by you) which will allow you to identify this thread in service from point 1.
3. Make some kind of pinger from client to server (for example on every 5 seconds client will ping processing service with thread id). Write last time of ping for this thread in thread-processing service.
4. In thread-processing service from point 1, create next thread for checking each thread if ping was in last 5 seconds. If not - interrupt thread.

Comment: this would have to be done using websockets or similar.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I am sorry, but I don't understand what do you mean. Solution described by me in answer can be implemented on pure servlets.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you must load your page to afford javascript side bind events like closing browser window:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(eventObject) {...})
```

And in function you can generate [ajax request](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) to server side, which could serve like a marker to stop the thread.

When your page is requested you create a new thread for your heavy task and add [timer](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) to page, which polls server at some interval to see if the task is complete (also via ajax). When the task is complete you are free to choose what to do - redirect to real page or update this page to load results.

Comment: I think this is not the best idea to depend on client ajax request to stop this heavy loop. If everything will be fine, then this approach is ok. But what if for example client suddenly lost internet connection? Heavy loop will still work on server.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but on the other hand if clients request transmission will be delayed for some reason (bad connection for example or disconnect and subsequent connect) your approach will terminate the task and user will have to reload this task again.

Comment: Yes that true, but 5 seconds is just example value for ping. You can always make some kind of server-push (client requests server, server holds response for while - for example 1 minute - and returns it; then client in callback requests again) with some timeouts (for example 15 seconds). If client is not available in 15 seconds becouse of connection problems, then I think you will never prepare for that.

Comment: Agreed. Such approach could be implemented by using ajax requests too. Could you explain how to do this without websockets or ajax from the clientside? Servlets are managing requests, but how to push such requests from client periodically?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, sorry but by request I mean ajax request above. Unfortunately I don't know how to achieve this without ajax requests. I've used above solution several times in production webapps and always work very good ;)